# Can "being" be used to ask questions?

Tags: usage

Let's say someone explains you something. But it's not clear where (s)he's getting at, or what's the point. Then at some point you can say, "And the point being... what exactly?"

Now, let's say someone wants you to send him/her a parcel. (S)he tells everything save for the address. Can I ask, "And the address being?.." I guess I can't, but why? If I can, then again, why? Also I guess sentences that start with "Meaning, ..." are somehow relevant here.

Comment: Yes, you can use phrasings like "the address being...?" just like you would use "the point being...?"  It's like prompting someone to complete a participial phrase that should have gone with their original sentence.  But I think its use also depends heavily on context.

Comment: It would be better to leave out the 'And'. It can be used in explanations too - "I can't meet you tomorrow, the reason being that I have to visit my grandparents." Using it as a question is like prompting the other person to give the explanation.

Comment: I'd definitely say "And the address is?" Also, "And the point being?" isn't a very nice thing to say to anyone - it's insulting and patronising because it implies that what they're saying is pointless and worthless.

Comment: @StuartF By accident, I've just [ran](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nJFtfmbj8zU&t=301s) into an [example](http://www.samizdat.qc.ca/arts/lit/PDFs/HideousStrength_CSL.pdf) (C.S. Lewis, That Hideous Strength), '“The job being... ?” said Feverstone, not exactly glancing, much less winking, at Mark, but making him feel that he was somehow being included in the fun.' It doesn't look like anyone is being insulted. I don't think the pattern is inherently insulting. Pointless and worthless?...

Comment: ...It can apparently mean that, but it depends one who says it, how (s)he says it, the target person, and generally on the context. It can be pretty much neutral. (That is, if someone points out my mistake, that's rather welcome, as long as the person is criticizing my actions, not me myself.) At least that's the impression I've got so far. But to be safe, it apparently should be avoided. Speaking of which, what's the difference? And the address being/is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it's *grammatically* correct to say, "And the address being...?", as with "And the point being...?" it's *rather rude*, and clearly implies that the other person is doing a bad job of explaining.

Saying that in an otherwise normal interaction would likely be taken as hostile.

I'd only say something like that to a close friend that I have insulting banter with.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, both phrases (the point/address being) are rather rude or can be rude. If I use "is" ("And the point/address is?"), does that make any difference? If so, can you explain why?

Comment: With "is", it's less clear whether the intent is rude. How the listener understands your tone of voice would make the difference. As a native speaker myself, I wouldn't use "And the address is..." because of the real risk of a sensitive person misunderstanding my tone. "And the address?" (without "is" or "being") is safer and natural in the context of someone taking an order for delivery of a parcel.

Comment: Do you by any chance understand why it's less clear with "is"? Because the phrase is shorter? Because "being" makes it sound like, "All this time you were speaking I've been waiting for the address, and still is"? Anything else?

Comment: It's common to use "is" both when you're being rude, like with "being", and when you're being normal. That's why it's less clear.